# Как посчитать окончательную цену пиццы при выборе дополнительных ингредиентов из чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript

Есть форма при которой мы можем выбрать хотим ли мы дополнительных ингредиентов к пицце. Добавки с ценами в чекбоксах. При нажатии на Submit нужно вывести окончательную цену на екран

```html
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <h1>add-ons</h1>
            <p>
                Total price: <span id="price">0 USD</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class='panel'>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <form>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox">All add-ons</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Cheese, 3,50 USD</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="2.20">Sous, 2,20 USD</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="5.00">Ham, 5 USD</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="4.10">Pineapple, 4,10 USD</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" data-price="3.50">Mushrooms, 3,50 USD</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox">Clean</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        <button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: и в чем проблема? собираете все инпут элементы, собираете все чекнутые, суммируете значение атрибута датапрайс и выводите на экран

Comment: Исправьте орфографические ошибки и уточните "должны" или "можем" выбрать.

Comment: @Taras Что-то я не вижу Ваших попыток сделать все эти вещи.

Answer (score 0):

```
let elements = document.forms.myform.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
let button = document.querySelector('.btn');
let  totalCost;

button.addEventListener('click', fn);

function fn(){
 totalCost = 0;
  for(item of elements){
    if(item.checked){
      totalCost += parseFloat(item.getAttribute('data-price'));
    }
  }
}
```

Не забудь добавить id в форму`<form id="myform"></form>`